# Are there any specific languages which can be used with multi-tenant architecture?

Tags: multi-tenant

Can I use AngularJS NodeJS and mongoDB in a multi-tenant application or are there any restrictions for that? Please consider I am novice to multi tenancy and am bit confused about suitable technologies which should be used in a multi - tenant web application.

Comment: Do you understand what multi-tenancy is? Cause if you did, this wouldn't even be a question -- basically any tech stack can implement it, and the restrictions are the same for all (albeit baked into some more than others).

Comment: yeah @cHao I actually have the slightest idea about implementation using this architecture yet. I just wanted to make sure that I am in the right path anyway thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can get multitenant java app example from below link.

[Multi tenant Java app using spring & hibernate](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/02/13/using-hibernate-and-spring-to-build-multitenant-java-apps/)